# Automatic Reboot at specific time if Automatic Upgrade requires Reboot

Tags: ubuntu, automatic-updates, reboot

I have setup automatic updates and it updates automatically. However, there are updates that require a restart and I know

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";
```

will set it to reboot. But it reboots as soon as it updates. That could be at any time of the day, when my users are using my server. I want it to restart at a specific time, say 12:00 am that night. How do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades. You want `Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time`:

```
// If automatic reboot is enabled and needed, reboot at the specific
// time instead of immediately
//  Default: "now"
//Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "02:00";
```

It takes the time provided and uses it on `/sbin/shutdown -r` ([source](https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/blob/5f979a25fda0f399a6c426e9972ed4c2a0e15cf0/unattended-upgrade#L1713)). This means you can use any time that [`shutdown`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/shutdown) accepts, in your set timezone.

Comment: Do you know whether this time is in local timezone or in UTC? I don’t see this detail mentioned in [`unattended-upgrade(8)`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade.8.en.html).

Comment: I don't know. I guess it depends on whether apt has your TZ environment variable set.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable automatic reboot by setting in your configuration file :

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "false"
```

Reconfigure it :

```
dpkg-reconfigure -plow unattended-upgrades
```

Set a cron job to check the existence of `reboot-required` and reboot if needed:

```
crontab -e
```

Then append the above :

```
0 0 * * * [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ] && reboot
```

Save it and it's done.

`0 0 * * *` means to be executed everyday at 12AM (midnight), change it as you wish.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I had in mind. I was looking for a built in solution, but this works!

Comment: Great  ! Could you mark it as resolved ;)